# Product long description, additional info not showing for configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom, tabs, additional-information

Kindly help me out, I am not able to figure it out why the description tab nor additional info tab is showing for configurable product while it is working fine for simple product. I am using pagayo theme 003.

[image]

[image]
Thanking in advance.....

Comment: Please switch to Magento Default Theme & Check it's Showing or Not First